# NLog rule ordering

Tags: .net, logging, namespaces, nlog

I've seen a few examples of suppressing logs from a particular namespace but they all seem to suppress everything *except* for that namespace and not the other way around (that's to say, "give me enhanced logging for this namespace and suppress everything else" etc).

Would someone please explain why the following configuration doesn't suppress loggers in the `My.Namespace` namespace?  The goal is to ensure that any logger in the `My.Namespace` namespace is logged *only* for errors, while everything else is unaffected.

```
<configSections>
  <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
</configSections>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${level} ${message}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="My.Namespace.*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="console" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 1):

While I think it'd be clearer to be able to set a blanket rule for namespace suppression, I've managed to get this working with the following configuration:

```
<targets async="true">
  <target xsi:type="Console" name="console" layout="${longdate} ${level} ${message}" />
</targets>

<rules>
  <!-- Anything less or equal to DEBUG, don't write to anything (no target) -->
  <logger name="My.Namespace.*" maxlevel="Debug" final="true" />

  <!-- Anything greater or equal to INFO, write to the console target -->
  <logger name="My.Namespace.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" final="true" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
</rules>
```